# How to use angularJs to create a shopcart

Tags: angularjs

This is what I already made. http://jsbin.com/ducukege/1 
What I want is, when clicking on an item, both the count in the shopcart table and the red badge next to it change. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit your example a bit. Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsbin.com/bamifece/1